# Time complexity of k-th smallest number using PriorityQueue in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, time-complexity, priority-queue

I am trying to solve the popular interview question `Find the k-th smallest number in an array of distinct integers`. I read some solutions and found that a heap data structure suits this problem very well.

So, I have tried to implement a solution using the `PriorityQueue` class of the Collections framework, assuming that it is functionally identical to a heap.

Here is the code that I've tried:

```
public static int getKthMinimum(int[] input, int k){
    PriorityQueue<Integer> heap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

    // Total cost of building the heap - O(n) or O(n log n) ?
    for(int num : input){
        heap.add(num);      // Add to heap - O(log n)
    }

    // Total cost of removing k smallest elements - O(k log n) < O(n) ?
    while(k > 0){
        heap.poll();        // Remove min - O(log n)
        k--;
    }
    return heap.peek();     // Fetch root - O(1) 
}
```

Based on the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), the poll & add methods take O(log n) time and peek takes constant time.

1. What will be the time complexity of the `while` loop? (I think O(k log n)).
2. Should O(k log n) be considered higher than O(n) for the purpose of this question? Is there a threshold where it switches?
3. What will be the total time complexity of this code? Will it be O(n)?
4. If not already O(n), is there a way to solve it in O(n), while using the PriorityQueue class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What will be the time complexity of the `while` loop? (I think O(k log n)).

*O*(*k* log *n*) is correct.

> 2. Should O(k log n) be considered higher than O(n) for the purpose of this question? Is there a threshold where it switches?

You cannot assume that. *k* can be anywhere from 0 to *n*−1, which means that *k* log *n* can be anywhere from 0 to *n* log *n*.

> 3. What will be the total time complexity of this code? Will it be O(n)?

*O*(*n* log *n*), because that's the cost of building the heap.

It's possible to build a heap in *O*(*n*) time, but your code doesn't do that; if it did, your total complexity would be *O*(*n* + *k* log *n*) or, equivalently, *O*(MAX(*n*, *k* log *n*)).

> 4. If not already O(n), is there a way to solve it in O(n), while using the PriorityQueue class?

No. There exist [selection algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) in worst-case *O*(*n*) time, but they're a bit complicated, and they don't use `PriorityQueue`.

The fastest `PriorityQueue`-based solutions would require *O*(MAX(*n*, *n* log MIN(*k*, *n*−*k*))) time. (The key is to keep only the *k* smallest elements in the heap while iterating — or the *n*−*k* largest elements and use a max-heap, if *k* is large enough for that to be worthwhile.)